# How to replace an Object in pandas dataframe with another value in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this.

```
age gender edu income
15    m     MS   <=50
16    f     BS   >50
17    m     BS   <=50
```

Since this is a binary problem, i'd like all the <=50K values to be 0 and >50K to be 1. I've tried replace method and it didn't do anything.

```
data["income"].replace(["<=50K"], "0", inplace = True)

data["income"].replace( to_replace = "<=50K"], value = 0, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC:

```
data['income'] = (data.income == '>50').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   age gender edu  income
0   15      m  MS       0
1   16      f  BS       1
2   17      m  BS       0
```

Comment: @uharsha33 check the contents of the income column.  Maybe you have white space that needs to be accounted for.  is a boolean expression converted to integer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `map`

```
df.income=df.income.map({'<=50':0,'>50':1})
df
Out[328]: 
   age gender edu  income
0   15      m  MS       0
1   16      f  BS       1
2   17      m  BS       0
```

Comment: Its outputting NaN's